# What are the differences between ADF Power Query and Power BI Power Query? When would you use one over the other?

Tags: azure, powerbi, etl, azure-data-factory, data-wrangling

I have worked with Power Query in Power BI before and I know that you can wrangle data using Power Query in Data Factory, but why would you want to use one over the other? Are there any functional differences? I haven't been able to find any comparison documentation after several searches. What would be a good use case for using one over the other? Any insight or references to comparison documentation would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> why would you want to use the Data Factory version instead of the Power BI version

Power Query in ADF is translated to Spark and run on on-demand Spark clusters, so it's potentially much more scalable.  However it doesn't support all of the Power Query functions, so it's significantly harder to use.

Read the doc here [How Microsoft Power Platform dataflows and Azure Data Factory wrangling dataflows relate to each other](http://%20https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-query/dataflows/power-platform-dataflows-and-adf-wrangling-data-flows)

Comment: This is great, thank you. I saw this, but thought it was specific to ADF Data Flows and not Power Query. The headline seems misleading. Thank you, this helps!

Comment: "Data Factory Wrangling Dataflows" were renamed to "Power Query" to make clear that it's Power Query.  But the "Wrangling Dataflows" terminology has not been  updated everywhere.